# How can I clear/empty a file being piped to?

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection

Say I have some process which pipes to a file:

```
yes > foo
```

I now want to clear/empty the file `foo`, but still want the process to write to the file, i.e. start filling the file again after clearing.

Is this possible?

Comment: First write of your new batch should be ">" instead of ">>" and it will clear previous information...or just `rm -f <file>`

Comment: @Gravy: Does not work. No new file is created.

Comment: @downvoter: Care to explain?

Comment: can you provide the surrounding script so we know exactly what is trying to be accomplished?

Comment: I am using `yes`. I think this 'works as expected'.

Comment: @Gravy: So far experimented only with `yes`. I started `yes > test`, removed test, and then test was not recreated.

Comment: Try `yes >> foo` instead of `yes > foo` and do `> foo` separately to clear the file

Comment: @knub, posted !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `yes >> foo` instead of `yes > foo` and separately `:>foo` to clear the file

`yes >> foo` cause [`read` to open `foo` with `O_APPEND`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/202797/21233). This causes the file offset to be positioned at the end of the file before each write.

So `yes` writes to the file `foo`, with each write causing the file pointer to be positioned at the end of `foo`. Meanwhile `: > foo` truncates the file to 0 bytes. Now the next `yes` write, due to the re-positioning of file pointer at the "end" of the zero-byte `foo` induced by `O_APPEND`, starts over at the beginning of the zero-byte `foo`

Answer (score 0):

If you do `yes > foo` and do it again, it *does* remove any content that was in the file foo after the first execution...

You can use one of the following:

```
rm foo
yes > foo

> foo
yes > foo

echo "" > foo
yes > foo
```