# How to make appends to files fail if the file does not exist already?

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, gnu, bsd

For example

```
echo Something >> SomeFile
```

I want this append to work only if `SomeFile` exists already.

Right now I am using the following:

```
if [ -e SomeFile ]; then 
    echo Something >> SomeFile
fi;
```

But there should be a race condition here. During the if condition evaluation `SomeFile` may exist. A context switch happens between the if condition and the append. Some other application executes that removes `SomeFile`. In that case the append would create `SomeFile`.

I need to solution to work for both bsd sed and gnu sed.

---

It is pretty simple to do this in python with [os.open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open) and [O_APPEND](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.O_APPEND)

```
$ rm SomeFile
$ python -c "import os; print(os.open(\"SomeFile\",os.O_APPEND))"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'SomeFile'
$ touch SomeFile
$ python -c "import os; print(os.open(\"SomeFile\",os.O_APPEND))"
3
```

Comment: I do not think I can achieve this with `>>` (output-redirection). According to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202807/212862) `>>` operation opens files with O_CREAT.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should accomplish what you want:

```
sed -i '' -e '$a\
Something\
' SomeFile
```

I did this with mac osx/bsd sed so you may be able to remove the `-i ''` part.  This will fail if `SomeFile` does not exist however a caveat to this is it will also fail if the file exists and is 0 bytes, hopefully that isn't a deal breaker for you.

Comment: I have not used sed much except for simple replace `s/../../g`. So sorry for uneducated questions. For gnu-sed I needed to remove the `''` but not the `-i`. But in that case the gnu-sed appends one more extra line after `Something` Do you need the final new line in the sed script? 
I think I can work around the 0 bytes problem. I can make the file contain a new line at the start instead of being empty. Why is this command a NOOP for empty files? Is it because sed is line based and skips processing if it cannot find any lines ?

Comment: My issue with this solution is portability. I need the solution to work in BSD and in Linux. I will update the question accordingly. It should not be too difficult to modify the parameters and the sed script to generate the same output for bsd and gnu seds.